# Access Table Validation Rule

Tags: validation, ms-access, if-statement

If my table has two fields [Field1] & [Field2] what would be the validation rule for logic as follows:

If [Field1] = 5 Then [Field2] = 1 Otherwise [Field2] can have any value.

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda straightforward.

```
([Field1] = 5 AND [Field2] = 1) OR [Field1] <> 5
```